# Overwrite CSS style

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a profile image on my site that is applied the following CSS style:

```
img {
    height: auto;
}
```

I need to basically switch off or remove the `auto` with my own custom style, but just can figure out how to achieve that.

I've tried to replace the auto with `none`, `inherit`, `unset`, all followed by the `!important` tag, but none of them seems to do the job.

Any ideas?

Comment: There might some other dependent styles.. Can you show us the link possibly if your site's live?

Comment: Try `height: initial`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. `auto` is the default and logical setting for height so `initial` is `auto`, i.e., browser-calculated. If you don't want that, then you need to define a fixed height.

Comment: 1. What do you want it to be? ... 2. How does the markup look like for that particular element?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve actually? Just setting a height to some value overrides the auto. Provide more code / info.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a clean solution without having a live example of your css code.

If your `img` element is not constrained by other elements, using `!important` would normally works (but you really you should not use `!important`).

On the other hand, the initial value for the `height` property **is** `auto`, so you can't really *reset* it to something else. You can however set another value like :

```
img {
    height: 100vh !important;
}
```

You can change it to a specific value, but again, `auto` [is the default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) : `Initial value : auto`. Using `unset` would just default it back to `auto`.

Comment: Is it possible to unset it? Remove the style completely with my own style?

Comment: @JoeBloggs You unset a given value by giving it a new value, does that make sense?

Comment: @JoeBloggs As I said, your style being already 'auto', it's also the default style, so 'unsetting' it won't change a thing, on the other hand you are free to set it to any other value to your liking. Please do not forget to accept the answer if you think it answered your question.